# Agora Web SDK NG - stop screen share event exists?

Tags: javascript, agora.io, screensharing, agora-web-sdk-ng

currently I am using Agora Web SDK NG for video call implementation on web. I have one theoretical question. I started work on screen share.  I will use example. I have video call members A and B. User A starts a screen share. Sharing is working fine, but problem occurs when user A wants to stop the screen share. User A click on **standard Agora Stop share button** which is shown from the screen share beginning.[image: .]

After click, sharing is stopped but this change is not reflected to user B. The current video stream from user A stucked, because the stream was not unpublished. And this is my main problem. On user A side, I am not able to detect the button click on Agora standard stop share button. This button is outside of browser context so I am not able to just make selector and create button click event. If I would be able to detect this button click, I am able manually unpublish the stream. Do you know how to do it? I would expect some event handler something like this client.on("user-stop-share", handlerFunction). I am using Google Chrome browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To close this bar you can use a track-ended event.
Here the track is the instance of await AgoraRTC.createScreenVideoTrack.

```
 rtc.track.on('track-ended', () => {
      console.log('stopScreenSharing')
      })
```